# I'm going to delete the index designated as a repeat statement. I can't tell what to do. Help me

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd

delete_counts = [1,2,3,4]
df = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
column_name = ["number"]

# 엑셀파일 pandas로 변환하기
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=column_name)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([], columns=column_name)
print(df)

for delete_count in delete_counts :
    count = int(delete_count)
    set_df = df[df['number'] != count]
    set_df.append(df2)
    print(set_df)
       
print(df2)
```

I am currently finding and doing various ways. But I can't find the way I want. I desperately need help now.

Comment: do you want to remove the rows mentioned in the delete_counts from your df?

Comment: That's right. I want to remove the row mentioned in delete_count.
delete_count is a number that I can arbitrarily designate.
Simply put, df2 = df[df["number"!]!=1,10] We're experiencing a problem now because we can't separate the dataframe even if we try to turn the for statement.

Answer (score 0):

Please re-write your code as below;

```
import pandas as pd

delete_counts = [1,2,3,4]
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], columns = ["Number"])
df
```

**Output:**

```
    Number
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
6   7
7   8
8   9
9   10
```

To remove the rows that contain the value in your delete_count,

```
df.loc[~df['Number'].isin(delete_counts), :]
```

**Output:**

```
Number
4   5
5   6
6   7
7   8
8   9
9   10
```

You can reset the index if you need to, using reset_index method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin()` to find the elements of list inside dataframe. Also use `~` to exclude those rows.

```
df2 = df.loc[~df['number'].isin(delete_counts)]
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
df2
```